# Unix Tar Command with previous find result

Tags: linux, find, tar

Let's suppose we have 4 files:

```
a.zip created on 28 feb 2018
b.zip created on 28 feb 2018
c.zip created on 2 mar 2018
d.zip created on 2 mar 2018
```

I want to search the 28 Feb files and Tar it.

```
find ./ -type f -ls | grep 'Feb 28' | tar -czf somefile3.tar --null -T -
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With GNU or FreeBSD `find` and GNU or BSD `tar`:

```
find . -type f -newermt 2018-02-28 ! -newermt 2018-03-01 -print0 |
  tar -cf file.tar --null -T -
```

<sup>(note that it excludes files last-modified at the exact nano-second 2018-02-28T00:00:00.000000000 (and could include a file at the time the next day) which on filesystems with nano-second granularity would almost never happen unless the files were created with `touch -t`/`touch -d` or were themselves extracted from archives that don't store timestamps with sub-second precision)</sup>

POSIXly and assuming file names don't contain newline characters (the standard tar archive format also has extra limitations on file names):

```
touch -d 2018-02-28T00:00:00 .start
touch -d 2018-03-01T00:00:00 .end
find . -type f -newer .start ! -newer .end ! -path ./.start ! -path ./.end |
  pax -x ustar -w > file.tar
```

If you wanted all the regular files last modified on any Feb 28, not just 2018, with GNU tools:

```
find . -type f -printf '%Tm-%Td-%p\0' |
  sed -nz 's/^02-28-//p' |
  tar -cf file.tar --null -T -
```

The output of `find -ls` is not post-processable automatically reliably, it's only intended for human consumption.

Comment: The problem in this case is that you either skip a second or get two days if you are on a leap year.

Comment: @schily, yes for leap years you'd need `! -newermt 2016-02-29`. On Linux native file systems (as tagged by the OP), that would be one nano-second missing (and one possibly added) as already noted. With `! -newermt 2018-02-28T23:59:59`, that's an entire second missing (1 billion as much), an entire minute with your `touch -t` approach. The `find -printf` approach doesn't have the issue.

Comment: OpenBSD `find` does not have `-newermt`. One would have to touch a separate file and use `-newer` instead on this system.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ah OK. IIRC `-newermt` originated in BSDs, a shame OpenBSD didn't pick it up.

Comment: As mentioned already, `-newermt` looks like a nice enhancement for `find` and FreeBSD did already added an enhancement to their find that I invented in the 1980s: see `-mtime -3y4w` and that is in `libfind`.

Comment: BTW: there is a problem with 'find | tar' . While it seems that `find` implementations since a while all support "unlimited" path length, all tar implementations except `star` don't support that. Star in the most recent version supports "unlimited" path length (8 GB) since a week via `star -c -find` and this week, there will be a new version that also supports unlimited path length using the vanilla `star -c` command line.

Comment: Also relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321753/135943

Comment: BTW: I just published a new schilytools tarball that includes the now complete conversion of star for very long path name support. A funny note: GNU tar-1.30 seems to accidently support long path names with `gtar -c` but it cannot extract the so created archives and `gtar -c -T -` still does not support long path names.

Comment: @schily, thanks. Does that involve an extension to the tar format? Would other tar  implementations be able to extract those archives?

Comment: This does not change the tar archive format, since either the POSIX.1-2001 archive format or the pre-POSIX method support path names up to 8 GB. Other tar implementations would need to add complete support for the *at() syscalls and to dynamic path storage in order extract archives with long path names. As mentioned before: gtar-1.30 accidently creates such archives with `gtar -c` and cannot extract the own archives that have been created this way.

Answer (score 4):

With `star`, your command line looks:

```
touch -t201802280000 ref
star -c -f file.tar -find . -newer ref
```

BTW: -newermt may be a nice future enhancement for `libfind`.

If you like an end date as well:

```
touch -t201802280000 start
touch -t201802282359.59 end
star -c -f file.tar -V pat='start!end' -find . -newer start ! -newer end
```

Note that you either have to omit one second or you may get two days if the years was a leap year.

Since 2018 isn't a leap year, you may use `touch -t201803010000 end`.

Answer (score 3):

`find` has *date* options. did you try those?

> -newermt last modified date
>
> -newerat last accessed date
>
> -newerct last date that permissions changed

for example:
`find . -newermt 2018-07-10 ! -newermt 2018-7-11 | xargs tar -cfv file.tar`
**EDIT**
as [Charles Duffy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457916/unix-tar-command-with-previous-find-result/457932?noredirect=1#comment832366_457932) comment , to avoid this problem:
`find . -newermt 2018-07-10 ! -newermt 2018-7-11 -print0 | xargs -0 tar -cfv file.tar`

Comment: This looks like it was added an hour after [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457923/3113) concretely showing those options, with more-portable/less-buggy `xargs` usage? (Note that `xargs` without `-d` or `-0` arguments behaves badly with filenames with spaces, filenames with literal quote characters, etc).

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add the reason your command is not working

```
find ./ -type f -ls | grep 'Feb 28' | tar -czf somefile3.tar --null -T -
```

The output of find is a list of filename together with other information like the date. Grep outputs the full lines with the matching date. Tar expects just the names of the files, and it expects that separated by null-bytes and not newlines.